# How to upload user location to server every 10 seconds when app is killed?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am doing it in the background by using timer. How do I do it when the app is killed?

Comment: You need background location permission. If you use best accuracy you will get an update every second or so. You can simply keep track of the last time you sent a location and send a new location if more than 10 seconds has elapsed. This is not very battery friendly, however.

Comment: That doesn't work when app is killed

Comment: Right sorry, you also need to use significant location change monitoring, but that is only every 500m or so and you will need always permission.  That is the best you will get

Answer (score 1):

When app is killed there is no way to wake up app and send the user location on server for every 10 seconds. When the app is killed you have no access/control over the app to wake up it after 10 seconds.

There is an alternet way using a background fetch but for every 10 seconds it is not possible with background fetch too.

Comment: How frequent can I send location using background fetch when app is killed?